# What are some reasons a RegisterMessageHandler might not execute its message processing function?

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

Please bear with me as I'm very new to using Azure services. I'm using a service bus topic to read messages, and I have a RegisterMessageHandler for processing. I have been having problems on and off with the handler actually calling the function I pass to it. My code looks like this:

```
private void RegisterOnMessageHandlerAndReceiveMessages()
{
     var messageHandlerOptions = new MessageHandlerOptions(ExceptionReceivedHandler)
     {
         MaxConcurrentCalls = 1,
         AutoComplete = false
     };

     _subscriptionClient.RegisterMessageHandler(ProcessMessagesAsync, messageHandlerOptions);
}

private async Task ProcessMessagesAsync(Message message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
     // processing logic here
}
```

When I put a breakpoint in RegisterOnMessageHandlerAndReceiveMessages and in ProcessMessagesAsync, I can see that the line with _subscriptionClient is hit, but pressing Continue in debug mode doesn't jump into ProcessMessagesAsync. This was working a couple days ago, and the code I changed in the short time between then and now has nothing to do with either of these methods. What could be causing this?

Comment: Maybe there is still an (old) active filter on the subscription, which was set in an earlier test? I had a similar case after migrating my ServiceBus-related code to _Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus_. The default subscription had a filter applied and the MessageHandler was never Invoked. I was able to find and delete that old filter using the ServiceBus Explorer.

Comment: I just tried it by deleting the default filter that was applied (I never made on of my own), but unfortunately it still wasn't working. Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: What exactly did you change then? The sample provided doesn't look wrong. Did you make sure that messages are currently arriving? This may sound ridiculous, but sometimes one is just too focused on one thing.

Comment: I changed the processing logic, stuff that gets run after the message is fetched -- nothing related to dequeuing at all. I've tried reinstalling the package and double checked the connection string. There's 79 messages sitting in the subscription. I am probably thinking too narrow minded, but I'm too inexperienced to understand what else could be affecting this...

Comment: Are those 79 messages listed under _Active Message Count_ or under _DeadLetter Message Count_? Are you completing the messages at the end of their processing by calling `subClient.CompleteAsync(...)`? If you are processing them _Max Delivery Count_-times without completing them, they will be put to the DeadLetter queue and not be received again.

Comment: Yes it was exactly that -- getting dead lettered! I had no idea to check that or even what it meant until someone explained it to me haha. Thanks!

Comment: Ok great. One thing to note: if there are active messages in the queue, it doesn't matter if the MessageHandler is registered later after that. The messages will be processed anyways, as long as their Time To Live doesn't exceed or they are not DeadLetter-ed for any other reason.

Answer (score 2):

Someone helped me figure it out! I just needed to delay for longer after calling RegisterMessageHandler, since it is lazily instantiated, so adding Thread.Sleep(50000) pretty much fixed it.

Comment: In general, this API is intended for hosts where you'd register the handler and the process wouldn't exit right after.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I actually have a while loop that keeps the service running, so I still have no clear idea why the delay is necessary tbh lol.

Comment: You could create a `CancellatioTokemSource` and await on that instead of while loop. Fifty seconds sounds awefuly a lot and likely masquerades some other problem.

Comment: Happy to announce it was resolved, it ended up being some other issue that masqueraded as a problem with the service bus. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with handler RegisterMessageHandler call is that it is not awaited for full completion. while code is running, main thread calls the handler RegisterMessageHandler event and moves to the next statement, which actually it should not have; and eventually reaches end of code, thereby forcing the called delegate (in this case "RegisterMessageHandler" method) to abort. The solution I think is to put a timer based waited approach or some kind of polling mechanism to check if handler is running or not